# how to give background color for selected text in text view

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, uitextview

How can I give a background color for selected text in text view?

I'm developing text view based app and I have to change the color for selected text.

I tried using delegate methods but I haven't found any property like this. Can you please suggest a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by using own logic like.

Using

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Calculated the Area of framing which i want to add color of text and on tapping on done creating a custom view and drawing text on it with selected range of tetx in different color and remaining normally. and it is go on... I am maintaining all values in XML file to read/edit the data.

When we want to edit the text data removing the custom view and when we resign the textView adding custom view with exisitng values from XML file. Its Works as usual expected.

Thanks for all your support to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the selection color within AppStore limitation. In fact, considering MobileNotes.app's selection background color is also light blue despite the caret is brown, we can see that Apple doesn't intend to allow non-blue selection background color.

However, you can calculate the rectangles occupied by the selection, then make a colored transparent non-interacting UIView on top of it to simulate a change of background color.

---

You can change the selection color *globally* (within your app) by *overriding* the undocumented method `+[UIColor selectionTintColor]` (e.g. using [`method_setImplementation`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), etc.).

Comment: thanks for reply.
yes i know there is no way to change the background color in text view for selected text. But my requirement is like above. So please forward me suggestions how to resolve my requirement.

Comment: @madhu: "you can calculate the rectangles occupied by the selection, then make a colored transparent non-interacting UIView on top of it to simulate a change of background color."

Comment: "yes thank you, i am trying this but how to calculate rectangles when text view in edit mode"

Comment: @madhu: Calculate the bounds of each character by `-sizeWithFont:`, and accumulate them until to reach the end of selection. (All simple ways resort to undocumented methods.)