# text editing in text view xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, uifont

I have a text view in which text is displayed like this:

```
how are you?

Fine
```

Now if i set font for text view, then the same font is displayed for the two lines(ques and answer), however i want question to be displayed in one font and answer in some other font. How can i do this?

I set font like this:

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 440)];
textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT" size:14]];
textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    textView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Its look like same requirement. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183275/how-to-give-background-color-for-selected-text-in-text-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [UITextView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html):

> In iOS 6 and later, this class supports multiple text styles through
>   use of the attributedText property. (Styled text is not supported in
>   earlier versions of iOS.) Setting a value for this property causes the
>   text view to use the style information provided in the attributed
>   string. You can still use the font, textColor, and textAlignment
>   properties to set style attributes, but those properties apply to all
>   of the text in the text view.
>
> This class does not support multiple styles for text. The font, color,
>   and text alignment attributes you specify always apply to the entire
>   contents of the text view. To display more complex styling in your
>   application, you need to use a UIWebView object and render your
>   content using HTML.

So you cannot have two on the same page for iOS 5 or less because it is not supported. Just use a webview and an HTML file. for iOS6 maybe you can try using `attributedText` property of UITextView. This is available under iOS 6. Never tried it though.

Or have 2 different UITextView's (its ugly but thats what it is).

Comment: If i take UIlabel instead of UITextView, then how can i do this?

Comment: which part of your code is static? is the question static? or answer static? if any of them is static, then you can use UILabel instead.They are better for your memory management too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you wanted to create a chatroom like app?

if so, I recommend make it a UITableView. And then make different Cells to match different styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributed strings to achieve this, for example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *para1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"How are you?"];
NSMutableAttributedString *para2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\nFine"];
[para2 setAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]}  range:NSMakeRange(0, para2.length)];
[para1 insertAttributedString:para2 atIndex:para1.length];

self.textLabel.attributedText = para1;
```

Or with a single attributed string:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *para1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"How are you?\nFine"];

// Get the range of the last line in the string
__block NSRange range;
[para1.mutableString enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {
    range = [para1.mutableString rangeOfString:line];
}];

[para1 setAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor] } range:range];

self.textLabel.attributedText = para1;
```

Both examples result in:

[image: Output]

Comment: What if if i have the text in only one string say para1?..Actually this data comes from tableview's textLabel which contains both ques and the answer.

Comment: You can achieve the same result using a single attributed string, but you have to use the method: -addAttributes:range:. I'll update my answer to show both approaches.

Comment: I assume that the strings that you will be consuming are free-format, so I have modified my answer to find the range of the last line in the string and apply the blue attribute to that line. Let me know what you think.